# Polymer Starter Kit: how to work with the backend API?

Tags: polymer, backend, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I use Polymer Starter Kit 1.0.3.

My application have different types of pages. Some of them should render data received from request to backend API.

But when the application starts, all requests from all pages immediately start.

The question is how to do the right job with the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, the solution I found was to use methods in my elements to call a function that it request information to the backend when I really need it. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I think he's talking about observer methods: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#change-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

There is [iron-ajax](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax),this is the mainly element polymer work with backend.

Here is an example in my project

```
  <iron-ajax auto
             verbose="true"
             url="[[apiCategories]]"
             handle-as="json"
             on-response="_onCategoriesLoadComplete"></iron-ajax>
  <iron-ajax auto
             id="ajaxWeapons"
             verbose="true"
             url="[[apiWeapons]]"
             params="[[apiWeaponsParams]]"
             debounce-duration="300"
             handle-as="json"
             last-response="{{page}}"></iron-ajax>
  <iron-ajax auto
             verbose="true"
             url="{{apiCountries}}"
             handle-as="json"
             last-response="{{countries}}"></iron-ajax>
```

This is very useful, when param change or id change, the whole page's data will reload, the simplest way to work with backend.

Maybe you don't want to auto request, example in my code

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxUserRegister"
           verbose="true"
           url="{{apiUsers}}"
           method="PUT"
           on-response="_onUserRegisterComplete"
           content-type="application/json"
           handle-as="json"></iron-ajax>
<iron-ajax id="ajaxUserLogin"
           verbose="true"
           url="{{apiUsers}}"
           method="POST"
           on-response="_onUserLoginComplete"
           content-type="application/json"
           handle-as="json"></iron-ajax>
<iron-ajax id="ajaxUserGet"
           verbose="true"
           url="{{apiUsers}}"
           method="GET"
           headers="[[user.headers]]"
           on-response="_onUserGetComplete"
           content-type="application/json"
           handle-as="json"></iron-ajax>
```

You can also use backend source when you needed

```
com._userLogin = function () {
    var {inputAccount:account,inputPassword:pwd} = this;
    if (!(account && account.length >= 4)) {
      this.showToast('Wrong account');
      return
    }
    if (!(pwd && pwd.length >= 4)) {
      this.showToast('Wrong password');
      return
    }

    this.$.ajaxUserLogin.body = {name: account, password: pwd};
    this.$.ajaxUserLogin.generateRequest();
  };

  com._onUserLoginComplete = function (e, ajax) {
    if (ajax.response.error) {
      this.showToast('Login faield:' + ajax.response.error);
      return
    }
    this.user = ajax.response;
  };
```

In conclusion,define you backend resource as a `iron-ajax`, this is how polymer work with backend.